# Angular 2+ page is blank in IE / SharePoint

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I built a solution with Angular 5 that works fine in Chrome and Firefox in SharePoint 2013. However, using IE11 has been problematic. The index.html file was added to the SharePoint page by using a Content Editor web part. After disabling intranet Compatibility View, the page now works when I go to the actual HTML file but still shows as a blank web part in the .aspx file. Does anyone have any guidance on this?

I'm using the following pollyfills:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

EDIT: In Chrome, the ASPX file is pulling the JS, CSS, and other resources are being pulled in correctly such as `https://test.com/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom/ng5qrcode/dist/styles.ac89bfdd6de82636b768.bundle.css`.

However, in IE, this resource is being pulled in as 
`https://test.com/Pages/styles.ac89bfdd6de82636b768.bundle.css`

Comment: Did you have polyfill configured on your angular app.

Comment: Yes, I enabled all recommended polyfills.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your bundled stuff relative to your index.html page, try to use a base url in your `index.html` and use relative urls to load the bundles.

```
<head>
    <base href="url_to_your_index.html_page" />

    ...

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.ac89bfdd6de82636b768.bundle.css">
</head>

<body>
    ...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```